# Declaring multiple return types on function definition in Python

Tags: python, pep8

I've being having some trouble when commentating functions or methods that returns multiple variables as example:

```
def separate_dfs(dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> ?:

    there_is_only_one_column = False
    df1 = dataframe["column1"]
    
    try:
       df2 = dataframe["column2"]
    except KeyError:
       df2 = None
       there_is_only_one_column = True
    
    return df1, df2, there_is_only_one_column
```

In the example, the returned variables can be of 3 types: pd.DataFrame, None and bool. But i couldn't find anywhere in the pep8 guide that explained how to handle that.

I also don't know what to do when one variable can be more than one type (like df2 that might be pd.DataFrame or None).

Comment: That returns a _tuple_, and the second value is _optional_.

Answer (score 4):

The exact return type would be

```py
from typing import Optional, Tuple
def separate_dfs(dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, Optional[pd.DataFrame], bool]
...
```

When you are using Python > 3.8, You can use the builtin `tuple` to write your annotation.
When you are using Python 3.10 you can write it even more compact as

```py
def separate_dfs(dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame | None, bool]
...
```

Comment: Using -> tuple [...] was the first thing that i tried, but the following error was raised: 'type' object is not subscriptable. So I thought it was wrong.

Comment: Use from typing import Tuple. I update my answer